# How to not get white space caused by line breaks

Tags: html, css, text, layout

I generated some code with animaapp, but I think that's not the problem. The problem is that I have a long. The text height fit with the page height. But if I resize the browser window, so the text gets wider and shorter. This works really well, but the page height stays the same and you can see a white space between the text and the page ending.
This is my HTML:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8"/>
            <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" name="viewport"/>
<style> <!-- Here is the CSS mentioned below --> </style>
</head>
    <body style="margin: 0;
     background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0);">
            <input id="anPageName" name="page" type="hidden" value="deploy"/>
            <div class="deploy anima-word-break ">
                <div class="datenschutzerkl344rung">
                    Datenschutzerklärung<br /><br />1. Datenschutz auf einen Blick<br /><br />Allgemeine Hinweise<br />Die folgenden Hinweise geben einen einfachen Überblick darüber, was mit Ihren personenbezogenen Daten passiert, wenn Sie diese Website besuchen. Personenbezogene Daten sind alle Daten, mit denen Sie persönlich identifiziert werden können. Ausführliche Informationen zum Thema Datenschutz entnehmen<br />Sie unserer unter diesem Text aufgeführten Datenschutzerklärung.<br />Datenerfassung auf dieser Website<br />Wer ist verantwortlich für die Datenerfassung auf dieser Website?<br />Die Datenverarbeitung auf dieser Website erfolgt durch den Websitebetreiber.<br />Dessen Kontaktdaten können Sie dem Impressum dieser Website entnehmen.<br />Wie erfassen wir Ihre Daten?<br />Ihre Daten werden zum einen dadurch erhoben, dass Sie uns diese mitteilen. Hierbei<br />kann es sich z. B. um Daten handeln, die Sie in ein Kontaktformular eingeben.<br />Andere Daten werden automatisch oder nach Ihrer Einwilligung beim Besuch der Website durch unsere IT- Systeme erfasst. Das sind vor allem technische Daten (z. B. Internetbrowser, Betriebssystem oder Uhrzeit des Seitenaufrufs). Die Erfassung<br />dieser Daten erfolgt automatisch, sobald Sie diese Website betreten.<br />Wofür nutzen wir Ihre Daten?<br />Welche Rechte haben Sie bezüglich Ihrer Daten?<br />Ein Teil der Daten wird erhoben, um eine fehlerfreie Bereitstellung der Website zu gewährleisten. Andere Daten können zur Analyse Ihres Nutzerverhaltens verwendet<br />werden.<br />Sie haben jederzeit das Recht, unentgeltlich Auskunft über Herkunft, Empfänger und Zweck Ihrer gespeicherten personenbezogenen Daten zu erhalten. Sie haben außerdem ein Recht, die Berichtigung oder Löschung dieser Daten zu verlangen. Wenn Sie eine Einwilligung zur Datenverarbeitung erteilt haben, können Sie diese Einwilligung jederzeit für die Zukunft widerrufen. Außerdem haben Sie das Recht, unter bestimmten Umständen die Einschränkung der Verarbeitung Ihrer personenbezogenen Daten zu verlangen. Des Weiteren steht Ihnen ein<br />Beschwerderecht bei der zuständigen Aufsichtsbehörde zu.<br />Hierzu sowie zu weiteren Fragen zum Thema Datenschutz können Sie sich jederzeit<br />unter der im Impressum angegebenen Adresse an uns wenden.<br />Analyse-Tools und Tools von Drittanbietern<br />Beim Besuch dieser Website kann Ihr Surf-Verhalten statistisch ausgewertet werden. Das geschieht vor allem mit Cookies und mit sogenannten<br />Analyseprogrammen.<br />Detaillierte Informationen zu diesen Analyseprogrammen finden Sie in der<br />folgenden Datenschutzerklärung.<br /><br />2. Hosting und Content Delivery Networks (CDN)<br /><br />Externes Hosting<br />Diese Website wird bei einem externen Dienstleister gehostet (Hoster). Die personenbezogenen Daten, die auf dieser Website erfasst werden, werden auf den Servern des Hosters gespeichert. Hierbei kann es sich v. a. um IP-Adressen, Kontaktanfragen, Meta- und Kommunikationsdaten, Vertragsdaten, Kontaktdaten, Namen, Webseitenzugriffe und sonstige Daten, die über eine Website generiert<br />werden, handeln.<br />Der Einsatz des Hosters erfolgt zum Zwecke der Vertragserfüllung gegenüber unseren potenziellen und bestehenden Kunden (Art. 6 Abs. 1 lit. b DSGVO) und im Interesse einer sicheren, schnellen und effizienten Bereitstellung unseres Online-<br />Angebots durch einen professionellen Anbieter (Art. 6 Abs. 1 lit. f DSGVO).<br /> Unser Hoster wird Ihre Daten nur insoweit verarbeiten, wie dies zur Erfüllung seiner Leistungspflichten erforderlich ist und unsere Weisungen in Bezug auf diese<br />Daten befolgen.<br /><br /> 3. Allgemeine Hinweise und Pflichtinformationen<br /><br />Datenschutz<br />Die Betreiber dieser Seiten nehmen den Schutz Ihrer persönlichen Daten sehr ernst. Wir behandeln Ihre personenbezogenen Daten vertraulich und entsprechend der<br />gesetzlichen Datenschutzvorschriften sowie dieser Datenschutzerklärung.<br />Wenn Sie diese Website benutzen, werden verschiedene personenbezogene Daten erhoben. Personenbezogene Daten sind Daten, mit denen Sie persönlich identifiziert werden können. Die vorliegende Datenschutzerklärung erläutert, welche Daten wir<br />erheben und wofür wir sie nutzen. Sie erläutert auch, wie und zu welchem Zweck das geschieht.<br />Wir weisen darauf hin, dass die Datenübertragung im Internet (z. B. bei der Kommunikation per E-Mail) Sicherheitslücken aufweisen kann. Ein lückenloser<br />Schutz der Daten vor dem Zugriff durch Dritte ist nicht möglich.<br />Hinweis zur verantwortlichen Stelle<br />Die verantwortliche Stelle für die Datenverarbeitung auf dieser Website ist: Karl Rupp Goethestraße 10-14 64807 Dieburg<br />Telefon: +49-6071-9888-50 E-Mail: k.rupp@goehte365.de<br />Widerruf Ihrer Einwilligung zur Datenverarbeitung<br />Verantwortliche Stelle ist die natürliche oder juristische Person, die allein oder gemeinsam mit anderen über die Zwecke und Mittel der Verarbeitung von<br />personenbezogenen Daten (z. B. Namen, E-Mail-Adressen o. Ä.) entscheidet.<br />Viele Datenverarbeitungsvorgänge sind nur mit Ihrer ausdrücklichen Einwilligung möglich. Sie können eine bereits erteilte Einwilligung jederzeit widerrufen. Dazu reicht eine formlose Mitteilung per E-Mail an uns. Die Rechtmäßigkeit der bis zum<br />Widerruf erfolgten Datenverarbeitung bleibt vom Widerruf unberührt.<br />Widerspruchsrecht gegen die Datenerhebung in besonderen<br />Fällen sowie gegen Direktwerbung (Art. 21 DSGVO)<br /><br />WENN DIE DATENVERARBEITUNG AUF GRUNDLAGE VON ART. 6 ABS. 1 LIT. E ODER F DSGVO ERFOLGT, HABEN SIE JEDERZEIT DAS RECHT, AUS GRÜNDEN, DIE SICH AUS IHRER BESONDEREN SITUATION ERGEBEN, GEGEN DIE VERARBEITUNG IHRER PERSONENBEZOGENEN DATEN WIDERSPRUCH EINZULEGEN; DIES GILT AUCH FÜR EIN AUF DIESE BESTIMMUNGEN GESTÜTZTES PROFILING. DIE JEWEILIGE RECHTSGRUNDLAGE, AUF DENEN EINE VERARBEITUNG BERUHT, ENTNEHMEN SIE DIESER DATENSCHUTZERKLÄRUNG. WENN SIE WIDERSPRUCH EINLEGEN, WERDEN WIR IHRE BETROFFENEN PERSONENBEZOGENEN DATEN NICHT MEHR VERARBEITEN, ES SEI DENN, WIR KÖNNEN ZWINGENDE SCHUTZWÜRDIGE GRÜNDE FÜR DIE VERARBEITUNG NACHWEISEN, DIE IHRE INTERESSEN, RECHTE UND FREIHEITEN ÜBERWIEGEN ODER DIE VERARBEITUNG DIENT DER GELTENDMACHUNG, AUSÜBUNG ODER VERTEIDIGUNG VON<br />RECHTSANSPRÜCHEN (WIDERSPRUCH NACH ART. 21 ABS. 1 DSGVO).<br />WERDEN IHRE PERSONENBEZOGENEN DATEN VERARBEITET, UM<br />DIREKTWERBUNG ZU BETREIBEN, SO HABEN SIE DAS RECHT,<br />JEDERZEIT WIDERSPRUCH GEGEN DIE VERARBEITUNG SIE BETREFFENDER PERSONENBEZOGENER DATEN ZUM ZWECKE DERARTIGER WERBUNG EINZULEGEN; DIES GILT AUCH FÜR DAS PROFILING, SOWEIT ES MIT SOLCHER DIREKTWERBUNG IN VERBINDUNG STEHT. WENN SIE WIDERSPRECHEN, WERDEN IHRE PERSONENBEZOGENEN DATEN ANSCHLIESSEND NICHT MEHR ZUM ZWECKE DER DIREKTWERBUNG VERWENDET (WIDERSPRUCH NACH ART. 21 ABS. 2 DSGVO).<br /><br />Beschwerderecht bei der zuständigen Aufsichtsbehörde<br />Im Falle von Verstößen gegen die DSGVO steht den Betroffenen ein Beschwerderecht bei einer Aufsichtsbehörde, insbesondere in dem Mitgliedstaat ihres gewöhnlichen Aufenthalts, ihres Arbeitsplatzes oder des Orts des mutmaßlichen Verstoßes zu. Das Beschwerderecht besteht unbeschadet<br />anderweitiger verwaltungsrechtlicher oder gerichtlicher Rechtsbehelfe.<br />
                </div>
            </div>

        </body>
</html>
```

(I separated the code for a better overview)
This is my CSS:

```
   .deploy {
                        width               : 100%;
                        min-width           : 605px;
                        height              : 100vh;
                        min-height          : 4915px;
                        position            : relative;
                        overflow            : hidden;
                        margin              : 0px;
                        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
                        -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
                        background-color    : rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0);
                        opacity             : 1.0;
                        }

                        a {
                        text-decoration     : none;
                        }

                        div {
                        -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
                        }

                        .anima-full-width-a {
                        width               : 100%;
                        }

                        .anima-full-height-a {
                        height              : 100%;
                        }

                        div {
                        -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
                        }

                        .deploy .datenschutzerkl344rung {
                        background-color    : rgba(255,255,255,0.0);
                        top                 : 1.34%;
                        height              : 91.43%;
                        width               : 68.10%;
                        position            : absolute; 
                        margin              : 0;
                        left                : 16.03%;
                        transform           : rotate(0deg);
                        opacity             : 1.0;
                        font-family         : "Inter-Medium", Helvetica, Arial, serif;
                        font-size           : 18.0px;
                        color               : rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0);
                        text-align          : left;
                        letter-spacing      : 0.53px;
                        line-height         : 21.0px;
                        }

                        .anima-word-break {
                        overflow-wrap       : break-word;
                        word-wrap           : break-word;
                        word-break          : break-all;
                        word-break          : break-word;
                        }
```

I already tried some things but nothing worked, maybe personal code specific is better. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
.deploy {
                        width               : 100%;
                        min-width           : 605px;
                        height              : 100vh;
                        min-height          : 4915px;
                        position            : relative;
                        overflow            : hidden;
                        margin              : 0px;
                        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
                        -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
                        background-color    : rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0);
                        opacity             : 1.0;
                        }
```

To this:

```
.deploy {
                        width               : 100%;
                        height              : 100vh;
                        position            : relative;
                        overflow            : scroll;
                        margin              : 0px;
                        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
                        -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
                        background-color    : rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0);
                        opacity             : 1.0;
                        }
```